# Is my extremely simple website safe agains XSS?

Tags: javascript, python, html, security, xss

I made a website that gets your request path and returns it in a `<link>` tag like this:

`<link rel="canonical" href="PATH_HERE">`

You can go to any path you want and insert whatever you want in there, and the only the thing that gets sanitized are double quotes (`"`).

The backend:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Catch every possible route
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': '/'})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    path = path.replace('"', "&quot;")
    return f"""
<head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="{path}">
</head>
    """

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

Here's the HTML returned when making a request to `https://website.com/hello`:

```
<html><head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="hello">
</head>
    <body></body></html>
```

And here's the HTML returned when making a request to `https://website.com/"</link><script>alert(1)</script>`:

```
<html><head>
    <title>Website</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="&quot;</link><script>alert(1)</script>">
</head>
    <body></body></html>
```

I'm wondering if it's even possible to make use of XSS in this website?

Comment: Note that that appears to be improper usage of a canonical `<link>` - the href is supposed to be the canonical link (presumably the root), not the current page. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element)

Comment: This `<link>` element is only used by search engines, it doesn't affect the users of your site. Browsers ignore it, so it can't cause XSS.

Comment: @Barmar what if it was an `<input>` tag instead, would it also be the same?